# Displaying Archives List

Tags: archives, sidebar, date, formatting

I'm displaying  list or archives using

```
<?php get_archives('monthly', '', 'html', '', '', FALSE); ?>
```

and my list displays

December 2012 
November 2012 
etc

However I would like to format this to display:

12.12
11.12
10.12
etc

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know about the date format unfortunately, but `get_archives` has been deprecated and replaced with `wp_get_archives`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is but the filter sucks, it only gives you the link HTML:

```
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse74891_archives_link' );
function wpse74891_archives_link( $link ) {
    $link = preg_replace_callback( '/>([A-Za-z]+\s+\d{4})/', function( $matches ) {
        return '>' . date( 'm.y', strtotime( $matches[1] ) );
        }, $link );
    return $link;
}
```

Using this method you can pass in any date format you want for the link at least.

Comment: mate you are star, that did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the date display format under *Settings > General* in your WordPress admin. Choose the **custom** option and enter `y.m` into the box.

[image]

If you're feeling adventurous, there are lots of other formatting tags [available](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)

Comment: The date format in settings only applies to post dates - the archive links are kinda hard coded.

Comment: yes that doesn't work